# Display child records under parent in php codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a Tbl containing below fields.I am able display only the first level and displaying fine.But I want to get the child details of each parent display under respective parent .please help me thanks in Advance.

```
id pid  name
1   0   proc
2   0   prod
3   0   dash
4   3   dash-prod
```

### this is my modal code

```
function get_all_access_list(){
    $db = $this->connect_db();
    $output =array();
    $db->select('access_module_id,access_parent_module,access_module_name');
    $db->from('access_permissions');
    $db->where('access_parent_module =',0);
    $query = $db->get();
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        $output = $query->result();
    }
    return $output;
}
```

### this is in view code

```
<?php 
if( !empty($access_list) ){
    foreach( $access_list AS $acces_name ){ ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="access_name[]" id="acces_name" value="<?php echo $acces_name->access_module_id; ?>">
        <span class="label-text fa-lg"><?php echo $acces_name->access_module_name;?></span>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Will raw query work for you ? and then you can convert it into CI format ?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of MySQL query, we can define a custom sorting parameter. If the `pid` value is 0, we can simply use the `id` value to sort upon; else the `pid` value. This is because the `pid` value for other levels is same as the `id` for the parent.

We will also use multiple level `Order By`, with second level ordering done using `id`.

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  t.id, 
  t.name 
FROM 
  your_table AS t 
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN t.pid = 0 THEN t.id 
       ELSE t.pid 
  END
  , t.id
```